# Find which item was clicked under which TreeviewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView named tvSearchResults.
In this Treeview I have two TreeViewItems

```
     TreeViewItem tvCategorieNodes = new TreeViewItem();
     TreeViewItem tvNotitieNodes = new TreeViewItem();
```

I do a query and the results of that query I add to this TreeViewItem by doing this (and the same for my tvNotitieNodes)

```
                    tvCategorieNodes.Header = "Category";
                    tvSearchResults.Items.Add(tvCategorieNodes);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in con.QueryEx().Rows)
                    {
                        tvCategorieNodes.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    }
```

So its for example

- Category

  - Category 1
  - Category 2
- Note

  - Note 1
  - Note 2

Now I want to know if a Category was clicked or a note because if the TreeViewItem is a category (in my database) I do

```
Select * from Categories
```

But if its a note I do

```
Select * from Notes
```

So the question: Is there a way to know under which TreeViewItem you clicked on a TreeViewItem?

Comment: You could use the field Tag to add the type of node to each of them.

Comment: i not get the question , is you want to selected item details implement TreeView_SelectedItemChanged event and check  Link : https://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview-wpf